# How to load file on google drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

What I need to do is to load file on google drive.

I am using **GoogleAccountManager** to authorize with oauth2 and get **AUTHTOKEN** and don't now what to do next.

To create Drive object I need **GoogleCredential** where I can get them?

```
Drive service = new Drive(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential);
```

Maybe I Should do similar thing to [Connect to the Online Service](http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate.html#ConnectToService) tutorial?

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists?key=" + your_api_key);
URLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.addRequestProperty("client_id", your client id);
conn.addRequestProperty("client_secret", your client secret);
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "OAuth " + token);
```

Then where this url comes from *"https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists?key="*

Please give me advice or sample code how to load file on google drive. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is now out of date as AccountManager authentyication has been deprecated in favour of Play Services.

**New Answer**

```
private Drive service;
private GoogleAccountCredential credential;

credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, DriveScopes.DRIVE);
credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
service = new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credential).build();
```

**Original answer**

I used this.  **AuthToken** is the token you received from AccountManager. **ApiKey** is the key you get from your [Google Apis Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console).

Seems to work so far. The documentation is very poor. Hopefully it will improve as it matures. It seems to be written for people who already know what they are doing regarding accessing G Api's. A complete sample would save so much time.

```
static Drive buildService(final String AuthToken, final String ApiKey) {
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

    Drive.Builder b = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null);
    b.setJsonHttpRequestInitializer(new JsonHttpRequestInitializer() {

        @Override
        public void initialize(JsonHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
            DriveRequest driveRequest = (DriveRequest) request;
            driveRequest.setPrettyPrint(true);
            driveRequest.setKey(ApiKey);
            driveRequest.setOauthToken(AuthToken);
        }
    });

    return b.build();
}
```

Comment: What type of Application did you set up to get your Client ID to get the ApiKey from Google's API Console? (IE, did you choose "Android" or "Other"?)

Comment: setJsonHttpRequestInitializer isn't defined in my edition of Drive.Builder, which I just downloaded from Google.  Any idea what happened to that?

Comment: setGoogleClientRequestInitializer looks like a plausible alternative.